# Decomposition of hyper-rectangles into congruent simplices

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, triangulation

Let $(a_1, \ldots, a_d) \in \mathbb{N}_+^d$ be positive integers and the semi-axes of the $d$-dimensional $\ell_1$-ellipse 
$$ E_{\bf a} := \{{\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^d: \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{x_j}{a_j} \leq 1 \}, $$
which also is a simlex with the $(d+1)$ integer vertices $(0,\ldots,0), (a_1,0,\ldots,0)$, $(0,a_2,0,\ldots, 0), \ldots,  (0,\ldots,0,a_d)$ .
Now, $E_{\bf a}$ is contained in $R_{\bf a} := \{{\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^d: \frac{x_j}{a_j} \leq 1 \}$, i.e. the multi-dimensional rectangle anchored at ${\bf 0}$ that has side-lengths $a_j$. We can assume that the a_j are ordered, i.e. $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \ldots \geq a_d \geq 1$.

In the two-dimensional setting $d=2$, we can decompose the rectangle $R_{\bf a}$ into
$$ R_{\bf a} =  E_{\bf a} \cup \hat{E}_{\bf a},$$
where 
$$\hat{E}_{\bf a} := \{ (a_1 - x_1, a_2 - x_2) | (x_1,x_2) \in E_{\bf a}  \}$$
also has *integer vertices*. Moreover, $E_{\bf a} \cap \hat{E}_{\bf a}$ is a null set and $\hat{E}_{\bf a}$ *is congruent* to $E_{\bf a}$.

Now comes my question: Is such a construction also possible in the higher dimensional setting, i.e. $d\geq 3$? I suppose (by comparing volumes) one needs at least $d!$ (congruent) copies of $E_{\bf a}$? Unfortunately, I have severe difficulties with spatial visualization and already for $d=3$, I was not able to figure out a valid decomposition of $R_{\bf a}$.

I hope someone can guide me to a solution or tell me the vertices of the $6$? tetrahedrons. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $d = 3$, you can choose the vertices $(0,0,0)$ and $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ to be common vertices of each tetrahedron, and then choose one vertex that has one non-zero entry, say in the $i$th position ($i=1,2,3$) and then choose one vertex that has one additional non-zero entry, say in the $j$th position where $j \neq i$.

This gives $6 = 3!$ simplexes, just like you suspected, and clearly they are all of the same volume, namely $a_1a_2a_3/3!$ because each is obtained by a permutation matrix multiplied by a shear matrix that has all $1$ on the diagonal and all $1$ above the diagonal, so the transformation matrix has determinant absolute value 1 and hence is volume preserving. Also the 6 simples have disjoint interiors, i.e. they form a valid triangulation.

However I don't believe these simplices are congruent unless you have a cube, i.e. all $a_i$ equal. This is because the 6 side lengths in $L_2$ norm are $|a_i|$,$\sqrt{a_i^2+a_j^2}$,$\sqrt{a_i^2+a_j^2+a_k^2}$,$|a_j|$,$\sqrt{a_j^2+a_k^2}$,$|a_k|$. This is not invariant under permuting the $i,j,k$ assuming the side lengths $a_i,a_j,a_k$ are distinct. I think it may be impossible to insist that the simplices are all congruent and also all have vertices that are vertices of the original box, which is traditionally how a triangulation works (i.e. all simplexes have vertices that are vertices of the original box).

In any event, clearly you can extend this decomposition idea to get equal volume simplexes that all have vertices that are vertices of the box, in any dimension, simply by taking each ordering of axes and then adding the sides in order starting at $0$ and ending at the opposite corner, for each possible permutation of sides. There are $d!$ distinct ways to do this, giving $d!$ equal volume simplices whose interiors are disjoint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if I choose $(0,0,0)$ and  $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ as common vertices, then none of the tetrahedrons from your construction is equal to my original simplex $E_a$. Is it possible to modify your approach that at least one or more tetrahedrons match $E_a$ ?

Comment: @User133713 You can get at least one extra simplex that is congruent to your original simplex. Let one simplex be your original, i.e. one vertex is the origin and the other $d$ vertices are the $d$ vertices connected by single edges to the origin. Then let the other simplex have one vertex which is the vertex in the opposite corner of the origin, along with the $d$ vertices that are connected by single edges to that opposite corner. These two simplexes have disjoint interiors and therefore they can be extended to a full triangulation by adding additional disjoint simplexes (this is a lemma)..

Comment: @User133713 However if you do that, I'm not sure if you can get $d!$ simplexes in the triangulation that all have equal volume. I don't think you can.